# Dynamic choice dataset Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently setting up a database for my thesis, but the way I am working is not efficient enough. I have got two datafiles that I currently need to link manually, but that takes too much time.

I have one spreadsheet that contains `Session ID` and `Visit Time` (which contains the click data of users on the website) and another spreadsheet that contains the `choice set` (which contains the choices the visitor could have made, the whole price listing).

> `Session ID sheet
>   Session ID        Visit time             shopname    click
>   1234              01-01-2012 08:30       Best Buy    1
>   1234              01-01-2012 08:30       Amazon      1
>   1235              01-01-2012 08:31       Best Buy    1
>   1236              01-01-2012 08:32       Best Buy    1
>   1236              01-01-2012 08:32       Craiglist   1`

Above data has been scraped from a website.

> `Choice set sheet
>   Position    Shopname    Price
>   1           Best Buy    €100
>   2           Amazon      €101
>   3           Craiglist   €102
>   4           Random      €105`

Above data has been extracted from an analytics client.

Now I want to have it in the following format:

> `The dataset
>   Session ID   Visit time         Click    Position  Shopname  Price 
>   1234         01-01-2012 08:30   1        1         Best Buy  €100 
>   1234         01-01-2012 08:30   1        2         Amazon    €101
>   1234         01-01-2012 08:30   0        3         Craiglist €102
>   1234         01-01-2012 08:30   0        4         Random    €105
>   1235         01-01-2012 08:31   1        1         Best Buy  €100 
>   1235         01-01-2012 08:31   0        2         Amazon    €101
>   1235         01-01-2012 08:31   0        3         Craiglist €102
>   1235         01-01-2012 08:31   0        4         Random    €105
>   1236         .....
>   ...
>   ...`

So basically, every unique session ID needs to have an separate choice set. I tried using `VLOOKUP` but I couldn't find a way to 'insert' a choice set list with each unique session ID, without messing it up since shopnames can have multiple session ID's.

Currently I am doing it all manually (copy pasting every session ID & visit time and copy every choice set for each ID), but this takes way too much time. Is there a faster way to do this?

Kind regards,

Comment: This is much better suited for a database, even MS Access. You can join on a primary key, but I can't tell exactly what that shared key would be.

Comment: @Raystafarian. I have thought about using MS Access, but the only shared key would be Shopname, as that is the only one that is included in both datasets. However, is it possible to create 'duplicates', as such as shown in the in the dataset I want?

Comment: I think they issue is, what choices were available? Right, so we know that this session, they clicked on A, but B,C,D were available. Next session, they click on A, but were B,C,D still the same as in the previous session? Are the options always the same regardless of the session?

Comment: It is product and day based. So each choice set is according to a product for one day (and this different each day, so I would have to create an separate database each day for each product).

So this could be an example for the iPhone 6 for example. And a different choice set is for the Galaxy S6, which I would have repeat those steps but in another database. In the end these two databases have to be merged together, but I guess there is a simple export to excel function, which I can combine them manually (or not?)

Comment: I guess I don't understand. In the first set for session 1234 you have a click for best buy and a click for amazon at the same time. But that doesn't show in the third set (example)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I should have looked at the example better. I have edited it now! It should indeed have shown 'two' clicks in the third set.

Comment: So the choice set should remain constant for, say, one entire day? I'm trying to figure out if there's a discernible pattern that you could use for VBA, or, better yet a table or pivot table. Right now, it really doesn't seem like a job for excel.

Comment: The choice set remains constant for half a day, so for every half day, the choice set remains constant. The click data and choice set is also extracted per half a day, as is the database. In the end, I combine all the databases into one large database for statistical analysis.